# Responsive canvas to remain at 100% of the div/screen size

Tags: html, css, canvas, bootstrap-4

I have a responsive canvas that should resize to the screen window within a div. There is a top menu navbar on the page, as part of bootstrap. The canvas is meant to be 1100x1100, but to resize and scale based on the screen size. The canvas should remain the same aspect ratio (a square).

However the canvas is expanding below the screen rather than filling the div size. Likely because of the top menu. It is also worth noting that the navmenu can collapse or be hidden, so it may not always be there which makes it difficult to force the canvas to resize x pixels lower.

How do I solve this so the canvas fits the screen, and there is no need to scroll? Is this a CSS solution or Javascript?

If you attempt to set the CSS width/height to 100% below, you can see how it no longer is a square and yet still runs below the height viewport. I desire for it to remain a square. (Note you need to click Full page to see this demo)

```js
// Init the canvas
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = 1100;
canvas.height = 1100;
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#4A4E69";
$idolCanvas=$('#myCanvas');

// Init the drag functionality
var isDragging = false;
var startX;
var startY;

// Arrays of the idols
var idols=[];
var NUM_IDOLS=0;

// Trigger the idols to load
for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
  idols[i].image.src=idols[i].url;
}

//////////////////////////////
// functions
//////////////////////////////

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    };
}

//TODO: return an array of ALL moved idols
function returnIdolsMoved() {
    for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
        var r = idols[i];
        if(r.moved) {
            return r.id + "," + r.x + "," + r.y;
        }
        
    }
}

// queue up another idol
function addIdol(name,x,y,scaleFactor,imgURL,id){
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = imgURL;
  base_image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, x, y);
  }
  //img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
  base_image.onload=startInteraction;
  idols.push({name:name,image:base_image,x:x,y:y,scale:scaleFactor,isDragging:false,url:imgURL,moved:false,id:id});
  NUM_IDOLS++;
}

// called after each idol fully loads
function startInteraction() {

  // return until all idols are loaded
  if(--NUM_IDOLS>0){return;}

  // set all idols width/height
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var img=idols[i];
    img.width=img.image.width*img.scale;
    img.height=img.image.height*img.scale;
  }

  // render all idols
  renderAll();

  // listen for mouse events
  $idolCanvas.mousedown(onMouseDown);
  $idolCanvas.mouseup(onMouseUp);
  $idolCanvas.mouseout(onMouseUp);
  $idolCanvas.mousemove(onMouseMove);

}

// flood fill canvas and 
// redraw all idols in their assigned positions
function renderAll() {
   
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
  //grd.addColorStop(0, "#fade57");
  //grd.addColorStop(1, "#51aae2");
  //grd.addColorStop(2, "#fc706f");
  //#56cc8f

  // Fill with gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    ctx.drawImage(r.image,r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
    if(r.isDragging)
    {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeRect(r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        var txt = r.name + ' [' + r.x + ',' + r.y + '] ' + r.moved;
        ctx.fillText(txt, r.x, r.y);
    }
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  }
    // axis lines
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    ctx.beginPath();
    canvas_arrow(ctx, canvas.width/2, canvas.height, canvas.width/2, 0);
    canvas_arrow(ctx, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height, canvas.width/2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    
    //labels
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
    ctx.font = "22px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F2E9E4";
    ctx.fillText('Seiso 清楚', (canvas.width+20)/2, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.font = "22px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F2E9E4";
    ctx.fillText('Intelligence', canvas.width-130, (canvas.height-20)/2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4A4E69";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

// handle mousedown events
function onMouseDown(e){
  scale_ratio=canvas.width / $idolCanvas.width();

  // tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  var mpos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  console.log("Mouse is at " + mpos.x + "," + mpos.y + ". Scale is " + scale_ratio);

  //get current position
  var mx=parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientX - $idolCanvas.offset().left);
  var my=parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientY - $idolCanvas.offset().top);

  //test to see if mouse is in 1+ idols
  isDragging = false;
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    if(mx>r.x && mx<r.x+r.width && my>r.y && my<r.y+r.height){
      //if true set r.isDragging=true
      r.isDragging=true;
      isDragging=true;
    }
  }
  //save mouse position
  startX=mx;
  startY=my;
}

// handle mouseup and mouseout events
function onMouseUp(e){
  //tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // clear all the dragging flags
  isDragging = false;
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    idols[i].isDragging=false;
  }
  //re-render the idols
  renderAll();

}

// handle mousemove events
function onMouseMove(e){
  scale_ratio=canvas.width / $idolCanvas.width();

  // do nothing if we're not dragging
  if(!isDragging){return;}

  //tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault
  e.stopPropagation

  //get current mouseposition
  var mx = parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientX - $idolCanvas.offset().left);
  var my = parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientY - $idolCanvas.offset().top);

  //calculate how far the mouse has moved;
  var dx = mx - startX;
  var dy = my - startY;

  //move each idol by how far the mouse moved
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    if(r.isDragging){
      r.x+=dx;
      r.y+=dy;
      r.moved=true;
    }
  }

  //reset the mouse positions for next mouse move;
  startX = mx;
  startY = my;

  //re-render the idols
  renderAll();

}

function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
  var headlen = 13; // length of head in pixels
  var dx = tox - fromx;
  var dy = toy - fromy;
  var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
  context.lineTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
  context.moveTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
}
```

```css
    body{ background-color: #22223B; }
    
    #myCanvas{
      
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: solid 1px white;  
      max-width:100%;
      max-height:100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin:auto;
      
    }
    
    .container-fluid{
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        
    }
    
    .nav-logo {
        width: 24px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light mb-1" style="background-color: #f2e9e4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="nav-logo" src="img/favicon.ico" alt="Chart logo">Chart</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="1" class="nav-link" data-bs-placement="auto" href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Help" data-bs-content="Desc">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="1" class="nav-link" data-bs-placement="auto" href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="About" data-bs-content="Desc">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="2" class="nav-link" href="URL" target="_blank">Feedback</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <button tabindex="3" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1">Your browser does not support HTML5.
        </canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try using view width - `100vw`, view width is relative to the view port...

Comment: did you set width: 100%, height:100% for canvas, not just maxwidth/height

Comment: Remove your inline style for position absolute and set your width to 100%, as long as it is a block level element, it should span the width of its parent.

Comment: You say that the canvas is 'meant to be' 1000x1000 - i.e. square - but are you wanting it to remain square or to just fill up both horizontally and vertically whatever is left to use on the screen?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, sorry. It should remain a square, I updated the question with that.

Comment: @dalelandry I just tried that, but it stretches the canvas out and the aspect ratio becomes wrong. It also does not solve the height being too tall, below the view height. Removing the inline position didn't change it either.

Comment: @PhúcHậuTrần Tried that, the height issue remains. It also stretched the width and is no longer a squad (I want it to remain a square).

Answer (score 0):

To maintain square you can add eventListener on `resize` and on `ready` event in which you can check for screen width and height and set canvas dimension accordingly.

Something like:

```js
const adjustCanvasHeight = () => {
    let maxSize = $(window).width();
    const otherSizesThatChangeHeight = $('nav').height() + 16 // 16px from body margin;

    if ($(window).height() - otherSizesThatChangeHeight < maxSize) {
        maxSize = $(window).height() - otherSizesThatChangeHeight;
    }

    $idolCanvas.css({
        'width': maxSize,
        'height': maxSize
    });
}

$(document).ready(adjustCanvasHeight);
$(window).on('resize', adjustCanvasHeight);
```

This code will set width and height of canvas to window width or height (depending which is smaller) preventing it from exceeding from your window and will maintaining square.

Below full code snippet

```js
// Init the canvas
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = 1100;
canvas.height = 1100;
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#4A4E69";
$idolCanvas=$('#myCanvas');

// Init the drag functionality
var isDragging = false;
var startX;
var startY;

// Arrays of the idols
var idols=[];
var NUM_IDOLS=0;

// Trigger the idols to load
for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
  idols[i].image.src=idols[i].url;
}

//////////////////////////
//// CHECK THIS
//////////////////////////

const adjustCanvasHeight = () => {
    let maxSize = $(window).width();
    let otherSizesThatChangeHeight = $('nav').height() + 16; // 16px from body margin

    if ($(window).height() - otherSizesThatChangeHeight < maxSize) {
        maxSize = $(window).height() - otherSizesThatChangeHeight;
    }

    $idolCanvas.css({
        'width': maxSize,
        'height': maxSize
    });
}

$(document).ready(adjustCanvasHeight);
$(window).on('resize', adjustCanvasHeight);

//////////////////////////////
// functions
//////////////////////////////

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    };
}

//TODO: return an array of ALL moved idols
function returnIdolsMoved() {
    for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
        var r = idols[i];
        if(r.moved) {
            return r.id + "," + r.x + "," + r.y;
        }
        
    }
}

// queue up another idol
function addIdol(name,x,y,scaleFactor,imgURL,id){
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = imgURL;
  base_image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, x, y);
  }
  //img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
  base_image.onload=startInteraction;
  idols.push({name:name,image:base_image,x:x,y:y,scale:scaleFactor,isDragging:false,url:imgURL,moved:false,id:id});
  NUM_IDOLS++;
}

// called after each idol fully loads
function startInteraction() {

  // return until all idols are loaded
  if(--NUM_IDOLS>0){return;}

  // set all idols width/height
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var img=idols[i];
    img.width=img.image.width*img.scale;
    img.height=img.image.height*img.scale;
  }

  // render all idols
  renderAll();

  // listen for mouse events
  $idolCanvas.mousedown(onMouseDown);
  $idolCanvas.mouseup(onMouseUp);
  $idolCanvas.mouseout(onMouseUp);
  $idolCanvas.mousemove(onMouseMove);

}

// flood fill canvas and 
// redraw all idols in their assigned positions
function renderAll() {
   
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
  //grd.addColorStop(0, "#fade57");
  //grd.addColorStop(1, "#51aae2");
  //grd.addColorStop(2, "#fc706f");
  //#56cc8f

  // Fill with gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    ctx.drawImage(r.image,r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
    if(r.isDragging)
    {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeRect(r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        var txt = r.name + ' [' + r.x + ',' + r.y + '] ' + r.moved;
        ctx.fillText(txt, r.x, r.y);
    }
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  }
    // axis lines
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    ctx.beginPath();
    canvas_arrow(ctx, canvas.width/2, canvas.height, canvas.width/2, 0);
    canvas_arrow(ctx, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height, canvas.width/2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    
    //labels
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
    ctx.font = "22px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F2E9E4";
    ctx.fillText('Seiso 清楚', (canvas.width+20)/2, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.font = "22px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F2E9E4";
    ctx.fillText('Intelligence', canvas.width-130, (canvas.height-20)/2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4A4E69";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

// handle mousedown events
function onMouseDown(e){
  scale_ratio=canvas.width / $idolCanvas.width();

  // tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  var mpos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  console.log("Mouse is at " + mpos.x + "," + mpos.y + ". Scale is " + scale_ratio);

  //get current position
  var mx=parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientX - $idolCanvas.offset().left);
  var my=parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientY - $idolCanvas.offset().top);

  //test to see if mouse is in 1+ idols
  isDragging = false;
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    if(mx>r.x && mx<r.x+r.width && my>r.y && my<r.y+r.height){
      //if true set r.isDragging=true
      r.isDragging=true;
      isDragging=true;
    }
  }
  //save mouse position
  startX=mx;
  startY=my;
}

// handle mouseup and mouseout events
function onMouseUp(e){
  //tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // clear all the dragging flags
  isDragging = false;
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    idols[i].isDragging=false;
  }
  //re-render the idols
  renderAll();

}

// handle mousemove events
function onMouseMove(e){
  scale_ratio=canvas.width / $idolCanvas.width();

  // do nothing if we're not dragging
  if(!isDragging){return;}

  //tell browser we're handling this mouse event
  e.preventDefault
  e.stopPropagation

  //get current mouseposition
  var mx = parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientX - $idolCanvas.offset().left);
  var my = parseInt(scale_ratio * e.clientY - $idolCanvas.offset().top);

  //calculate how far the mouse has moved;
  var dx = mx - startX;
  var dy = my - startY;

  //move each idol by how far the mouse moved
  for(var i=0;i<idols.length;i++){
    var r=idols[i];
    if(r.isDragging){
      r.x+=dx;
      r.y+=dy;
      r.moved=true;
    }
  }

  //reset the mouse positions for next mouse move;
  startX = mx;
  startY = my;

  //re-render the idols
  renderAll();

}

function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
  var headlen = 13; // length of head in pixels
  var dx = tox - fromx;
  var dy = toy - fromy;
  var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
  context.lineTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
  context.moveTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
}
```

```css
    body{ background-color: #22223B; }
    
    #myCanvas{
      
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: solid 1px white;  
      max-width:100%;
      max-height:100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin:auto;
      
    }
    
    .container-fluid{
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        
    }
    
    .nav-logo {
        width: 24px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light mb-1" style="background-color: #f2e9e4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="nav-logo" src="img/favicon.ico" alt="Chart logo">Chart</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="1" class="nav-link" data-bs-placement="auto" href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Help" data-bs-content="Desc">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="1" class="nav-link" data-bs-placement="auto" href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="About" data-bs-content="Desc">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a tabindex="2" class="nav-link" href="URL" target="_blank">Feedback</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <button tabindex="3" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1">Your browser does not support HTML5.
        </canvas>
    </div>
```